# ImageMagick's 'convert' won't set resolution?

Tags: resolution, imagemagick

I'm trying to create an image using imagemagick's "convert".

I have this command:

```
convert -size 720x480 xc:white -units pixelsperinch -density 81x72 foo.jpg
```

However, the image ends up with a 72x72 resolution, rather than 81x72.

```
identify -verbose foo.jpg
Image: foo.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Class: PseudoClass
  Geometry: 720x480+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 10x6.66667
```

When I run `convert` with `-resample 81x72` rather than `-density`, I get the correct resolution. Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-density` is not for resizing. From the ImageMagick page on [density](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#density):

> The -density option sets an attribute
>   and **does not alter the underlying
>   raster image**. It may be used to adjust
>   the rendered size for desktop
>   publishing purposes by adjusting the
>   scale applied to the pixels. **To resize
>   the image so that it is the same size
>   at a different resolution, use the
>   -resample option.**

`-resample` is just a simple wrapper around the `-resize` switch.

Comment: Cool, I didn't quite realize that it was just "modifying some arbitrary header" rather than actually setting the size; thank you for pointing out that part of the doc!

Comment: You're welcome! happy holidays :)

Comment: Hm, one more question: when I change to "resample", it changes the dimensions of my image (to 810x480). Do you know what I need to do to create an image which forces both my desired DPI and the desired dimensions?

Comment: Not even `-size 720x480!` (with the exclamation point!) does the trick.

Comment: 720x480 with 72 DPI? what is -density 72 -size 720x480 giving you? and with -resample 720x480?

Comment: For reasons that are magical to me, `convert -density 81x72 -size 720x480` was the incantation I needed to make it work. I tried "-density" again after your comment. Thanks again! (shouldn't you be playing with some new gizmo gift rather than tinkering on superuser? :-)

Comment: I mostly got money as gifts. Gonna go out and buy gizmo's tomorrow, this way I can choose what I want.